# Removing outliers from groups using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table object that contains group column. I am trying to remove outliers from each of the groups, however I cannot come up with the nice solution for that. My data.table can be build using simple script:

```
col1 <- rnorm(30, mean = 5, sd = 2)
col2 <- rnorm(30, mean = 5, sd = 2)
id <- seq(1, 30)
group <- sample(4, 30, replace = TRUE)
dt <- data.table(id, group, col1, col2)
```

I've been trying to split data.frame by group variable, however, it's too messy approach. How would I "easily" remove top n% of outliers from each group in data.table without having too many data transformations?

Comment: Outliers according what? col1? col2? Or both?

Comment: Outliers from both columns, but in more general case, outliers from any column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you want to remove outliers according to both `col1` and `col2`, based on the 95% quantile:

```
dt_filt <- dt[, 
    .SD[
        ((col1 < quantile(col1, probs = 0.95)) & 
         (col2 < quantile(col2, probs = 0.95)))
    ], by = group
]
```

which basically splits the data based on the `group` column, calculates the thresholds, and then subsets the data to keep only rows where `col1` and `col2` are lower than the thresholds.